# PopupMenuをToolbar中のメニューアイコンの下に出したい。

Tags: android

Toolbarのメニューのボタンをタップした時に、Popupメニューをそのボタンの下に表示したいのですが、Popupのインスタンス化の第2引数にToolbarインスタンスを渡すと、Toolbarの左はしにPopupMenuがでてしまいます。右側にだすにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

理想

```html
------------------------
Toolbar        ボタン
------------------------
               --------
               |popup |
               --------
```

現実

```html
------------------------
Toolbar        ボタン
------------------------
--------
|popup |
--------
```